# whereBetween() Eloquent returning wrong results

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Eloquent query and I am using query scope. I have a km column in my table and I am passing kmFrom and KmTo values as post data. Now I am doing a eloquent whereBetween and its returning wrong results when I search for km.

For example if I pass `kmFrom = 1000` and `kmTo = 2000`. Its giving me results which are not in between these two values.

Eloquent:

```
Product::categoriesCategoryId($categoryId)
            ->km($kmFrom, $kmTo)->get();
```

Query Scope for the km:

```
 public function scopeKm($query, $kmFrom, $kmTo)
    {   
        if(($kmFrom) && ($kmTo)){
            return $query->whereBetween('km', ["$kmFrom", "$kmTo"]);   
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

Please assist what wrong I am doing.

Comment: Try to use KM scope alone to see if the problem is in the `categoriesCategoryId` scope !!

Comment: Try removing the surrounding quotes from `"$kmFrom"` and `"$kmTo"`.

Answer (score 0):

It's different approach to doing same thing

```
public function scopeKm($query, $kmFrom, $kmTo)
    {   
        if(($kmFrom) && ($kmTo)){
            return $query->where('km','>' ,$kmFrom])->where('km','<',$kmTo);   
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

this will work same 
hope this will help you!