# mysql not returning proper results for this query

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a column km ( varchar ) in a table called products and and we save km values like how much a car has been driven. So a km could be any number that is saved. Now I want to query this column like I want results where km from 100 to 1000.

so the query looks like this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products1 
 WHERE categories_category_id = 1 
   AND subsubCategoryId = 1026 
   AND subcat = 174 
   AND categoryAdvertiseTypeId = 0 
   AND km >= 1000 
   AND km <= 5000 
 LIMIT 50
```

but what is happening is I get km not from this range. dont know why. Please tell me what could be the issue.

Comment: you can't do math on varchar, you'd need to either cast it or change it to an integer type

Comment: @Fred-ii- so I need to cast the value I am sending ?

Comment: Why you cast the value simply change the type it's easier.

Comment: @FoxCy I cant its an old database and it has million rows.

Comment: ok you've an answer below; try that. Edit: He deleted the answer. Edit 2: now it's undeleted.

Comment: Store integers as integers, not strings. Also, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: this also seems related to a previous question you posted earlier https://stackoverflow.com/q/46484573/1415724 where you didn't post the query for it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ahhhh *there there* lol!! btw, seems a form of repost, as per [my comment here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488002/mysql-not-returning-proper-results-for-this-query#comment79930791_46488002). Edit: what happened to "the pity vote"?

Comment: @Fred-ii- The bigger issue is whether he marked the previous answer correct.  If not, this should be downvoted as a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It seems related to me, seeing the code they posted for it.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out.

Comment: `'1000' <= '20' <= '5000'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast your kilometer `km` column to a number and then do the comparison.

```
SELECT *
FROM products1
WHERE
    categories_category_id = '1'  AND
    subsubCategoryId = '1026'     AND
    subcat = '174'                AND
    categoryAdvertiseTypeId = '0' AND
    CAST(km AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000
LIMIT 50
```

On the cosmetic side of things, I removed all those unnecessary backticks, which are ugly and make the query hard to read.

Comment: sure but they'd need to ALTER their varchar type column.

Comment: `Hi I have a column km ( varchar ) in a table called products` :D

Comment: I should have [made this an answer....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488002/mysql-not-returning-proper-results-for-this-query#comment79930409_46488002) from the beginning *haha!* - Well, you got the green ;-)